# How to pass size of array in function to function? I don't have “Variable-sized object may not be initialized”

Tags: c, arrays, arguments, parameter-passing, dynamic-memory-allocation

I want to pass the size of array, declared inside a function, to the same function. But then I got the warning "expressiong must a constant value". Are there solutions to this problem?

```c
// Draws a sprite in the console using hex-coded sprite with a specific width
void hex_to_sprite(char* hex_number, int width, int size)
{
    // hex_number = array of hex-coded sprite 
    // width = width of sprite you want to draw
    // size = length of the hex_number multiplied by 4 (0 = 0000, 1 = 0001, etc.)
    char binary_coded_sprite[size] = "";

}
```

Should I learn dynamic allocation to fight this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re declaring `binary_coded_sprite` as a *variable-length array*, where the array size isn’t known until runtime.  One of the restrictions<sup>1</sup> on VLAs is that they may not be declared with an initializer, so

```
char binary_coded_sprite[size] = "";
```

needs to be

```
char binary_coded_sprite[size];
```

and you’ll either need to use `strcpy`:

```
strcpy( binary_coded_sprite, “” );
```

or just set the first element to 0

```
binary_coded_sprite[0] = 0;
```

to initialize it to an empty string.

---

1. The other restrictions are that VLAs may not be declared `static` or at file scope, nor may they be members of `struct` or `union` types.

Answer (score 0):

From the code, it looks like the size variable is being computed from the length of the hex_number itself. So instead of passing the size variable in the function, just declare and compute the variable inside the function.

Comment: I have got the same problem

Comment: So you want to compute the size variable inside the function right?